# create value in another column based on conditional statement MYSQL yesterday's price

Tags: mysql

Hoping someone can help me this one:

I have this table that I want to create in MYSQL. I only have DATE and Closing Columns. I need to create a third column, but only categorial, where it's YES if that rows closing value is less than the row above it. Hence why those 2 columns on the top row are empty because the future price is not avaiable.

Also if possible a fourth column where the change from row above row is greater than 1%, then give it a 1 otherwise a 0.

```
DATE        Closing Change GOODorBAD

11/21/2017  155.5    -        -
11/20/2017  153.83  yes      1
11/17/2017  153.95  no      0
11/16/2017  154.54  no     0
11/15/2017  152.59  yes      1
11/14/2017  153.31  no      0
11/13/2017  153.87  no     0
11/10/2017  153.68  yes      0
11/9/2017   153.69  no      0
11/8/2017   154.5   no      0
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` conditions inside `SELECT`.

```
UPDATE TEST_TABLE T
  SET T.CHANGE = (SELECT CASE WHEN T.CLOSING < T2.CLOSING
                                THEN 'YES'
                              WHEN T.CLOSING > T2.CLOSING
                                THEN 'NO'
                              ELSE
                                NULL
                         END
                    FROM TEST_TABLE T2 
                      WHERE T2.DATE > T.DATE 
                     ORDER BY T2.DATE LIMIT 1),

      T.GOODORBAD = (SELECT CASE WHEN (T2.CLOSING - T.CLOSING) > (T.CLOSING / 100)
                                   THEN '1'
                                 WHEN (T2.CLOSING - T.CLOSING) <= (T.CLOSING / 100)
                                   THEN '0'
                                 ELSE
                                   NULL
                            END
                       FROM TEST_TABLE T2 
                         WHERE T2.DATE > T.DATE 
                        ORDER BY T2.DATE LIMIT 1);
```